# How to keep three select tags in a single line?

Tags: html, css

In this example, I have used three select tags for months dates and years but I need them in a single line. I have tried `display: inline-block;` but there was no change at all.

```html
<form name="c_month">
  <select name="cars">
    <option name="o1" value="1">January</option>
    <option name="o2" value="2">February</option>
    <option name="o3" value="3">March</option>
    <option name="o4" value="4">April</option>
  </select>
  </form></span>
  <form name="c_date">
  <select name="cars">
    <option name="o1" value="1">1</option>
    <option name="o2" value="2">2</option>
    <option name="o3" value="3">3</option>
    <option name="o4" value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  </form>
  <form name="c_year">
  <select name="cars">
    <option name="o1" value="2018">2018</option>
    <option name="o2" value="2017">2017</option>
    <option name="o3" value="2016">2016</option>
    <option name="o4" value="2015">2015</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you have each one wrapped into its own `form` element to begin with?

Comment: it's should be one form not 3

Comment: You probably don't want three separate forms for the select boxes. If you put them in one then make them `inline-block` you'll get the result you are after.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd suggest wrapping all of them inside one form element.

```html
<form>
  <select name="cars">
    <option name="o1" value="1">January</option>
    <option name="o2" value="2">February</option>
    <option name="o3" value="3">March</option>
    <option name="o4" value="4">April</option>
  </select>
  <select name="cars">
    <option name="o1" value="1">1</option>
    <option name="o2" value="2">2</option>
    <option name="o3" value="3">3</option>
    <option name="o4" value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  <select name="cars">
    <option name="o1" value="2018">2018</option>
    <option name="o2" value="2017">2017</option>
    <option name="o3" value="2016">2016</option>
    <option name="o4" value="2015">2015</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Unless you especially want 3 forms, then I'd suggest adding:

```
form {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I have edited as your suggestion and now I can see them inline.

Answer (score 6):

Try `display: flex;`

```css
.form{
  display: flex;
}
.form .items{
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="form">
  <form name="c_month" class="items">
<select name="cars">
  <option name="o1" value="1">January</option>
  <option name="o2" value="2">February</option>
  <option name="o3" value="3">March</option>
  <option name="o4" value="4">April</option>
</select>
</form></span>
<form name="c_date" class="items">
<select name="cars">
  <option name="o1" value="1">1</option>
  <option name="o2" value="2">2</option>
  <option name="o3" value="3">3</option>
  <option name="o4" value="4">4</option>
</select>
</form>
<form name="c_year" class="items">
<select name="cars">
  <option name="o1" value="2018">2018</option>
  <option name="o2" value="2017">2017</option>
  <option name="o3" value="2016">2016</option>
  <option name="o4" value="2015">2015</option>
</select>
</form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you've three forms, you have to set the following CSS:

```
form {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Normally the form element is a block element, so it takes always 100%. Another approach would be to set a specific width to your form elements and use floats like this:

```
form {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}
```

Here is the first approach:

```css
form {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="cars">
    <option name="o1" value="1">January</option>
    <option name="o2" value="2">February</option>
    <option name="o3" value="3">March</option>
    <option name="o4" value="4">April</option>
  </select>
</form>
<form>
  <select name="cars">
    <option name="o1" value="1">1</option>
    <option name="o2" value="2">2</option>
    <option name="o3" value="3">3</option>
    <option name="o4" value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</form>
<form>
  <select name="cars">
    <option name="o1" value="2018">2018</option>
    <option name="o2" value="2017">2017</option>
    <option name="o3" value="2016">2016</option>
    <option name="o4" value="2015">2015</option>
  </select>
</form>
```